# How to tell initial data load to insert only the values which are not there in target db?

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-golden-gate

i have some large data in one table and small data in other table,is there any way to run initial load of golden gate so that same data in both tables wont be changed and rest of the data got transferred from one table to other.

Answer (score 1):

Initial loads are typically for when you are setting up the replication environment; however, you can do this as well on single tables. Everything in the Oracle database is driven by System Change Numbers/Change System Numbers (SCN/CSN).

By using the SCN/CSN, you can identify what the starting point in the table should be and start CDC from there.  Any prior to the SCN/CSN will not get captured and would require you to manually move that data in some fashion.  That can be done by using Oracle Data Pump (Export/Import).

Oracle GoldenGate also provided a parameter called SQLPredicate that allows you to use a "where" clause against a table.  This is handy with initial load extracts because you would do something like TABLE ., SQLPredicate "as of ".  Then data before that would be captured and moved to the target side for a replicat to apply into a table.  You can reference that here:

https://www.dbasolved.com/2018/05/loading-tables-with-oracle-goldengate-and-rest-apis/

Official Oracle Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/admin/loading-data-file-replicat-ma-19.1.html

On the replicat side, you would use HANDLECOLLISIONS to kick out any ducplicates.  Then once the load is complete, remove it from the parameter file.

Lots of details, but I'm sure this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: Nice explanation, How do I get the SCN to start CDC once the initial load is over?

Answer (score 0):

That would require programming in java. 
1) First you would read your database
2) Decide which data has to be added in which table on the basis of data that was read.
3) Execute update/ data entry queries to submit data to tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Initial Load using GoldenGate:

- Target tables should be empty

> Data: Make certain that the target tables are empty. Otherwise, there
>   may be duplicate-row errors or conflicts between existing rows and
>   rows that are being loaded. [Link to Oracle Documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/wu_initsync.htm#GWUAD550)

- If not empty, you have to treat conflicts. For instance if the row you are inserting already exists in the target table (INSERTROWEXISTS) you should discard it, if that's what you want to do. [Link to Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/conflict_resolution.htm#GWUAD315)